# How or should I trust this?

Tags: loans, scams

I requested to take a loan from this person, But she/he does not give any information on who they are!? A few points answered. Please any answer I need help here.

**1**.Mister I am not here to dirty my reputation then I ask you to trust me and to fill the form if you really want that your transfer is quickly to make

**2**.I just read your message, and I want to tell you that I am committed to give you the loan of a sum of 100.000,00€/$. I offer you this loan at an interest rate of 2% with a repayment plan favorable. This being said, if you're ready to obtain this loan on the one hand, I am ready to help you. I put to your attention that you will pay the amount taken as loan with interest, which will be evaluated at a value 107.246,45€ and the monthly amount payable is 1.276,74€ for a duration of 84 months. You would start to pay from the dates 4 or 5 of each month.. If you are of the same opinion as me, then please kindly fill in the following form that will allow you to receive the funds in your bank account :

Name: ............................

First name: ............................

Country: ............................

City: ............................

Address: ............................

Postal Code: ............................

Sex: ...............................

Age : ..................................

Marital status :......................

Recipe monthly : .........................

The loan amount: ............................

Duration of the loan: ............................

Monthly payment: ............................

Profession: ............................

Phone number: ............................

Fax: ............................

Fixed: ............................

INFORMATION ABOUT YOUR BANK ACCOUNT TO BE ABLE TO PERFORM THE TRANSFER OF FUNDS

Account number: ............................

RIB: ............................

IBAN: ............................

PS : For me to confirm your identity; it will be necessary that you send me the scans of your identity card or passport.

PROCEDURE TO BE FOLLOWED FOR THE OPERATION OF THE LOAN

You will have a confirmation of the arrival of the funds in your bank account within 48 hours after the validation of the transaction from my bank. You need to guarantee the credit of the loan for any period of time of repayment. The transfer of funds to your bank account will be done by bank transfer.

You will begin repayment 3 months after the receipt of the funds in your bank account.

Good understanding of it.

Director : Daniela WIESE

THE SATISFACTION OF OUR CLIENT

Comment: This looks like a scam. You will not get your money, and worse, will lose some of yours in the process.

Comment: So, without knowing anything about you, they are "committed" to lending you EUR 100,000 at a rate of 2%.  All you need to do is provide them with all of your personal and banking details - including a scan of your passport/identity card!  Seriously!  Yes, it is definitely a scam.

Comment: Do not walk away from this "opportunity" -- ***run*** away.

Answer (score 14):

Why on earth would you request a loan from a person you do not know?  Don't do that.  This reeks of scam.

Comment: To the member that flagged this answer. Please add one of your own that you think better answers this question. Sometimes a rhetorical question is the perfect answer. I believe Freud said this.

Answer (score 6):

And you found this person via email?   It's not only a scam - it's *spam*.

Credit is a harsh business, and it sounds like you don't have enough experience yet to spot the scams.  Until you do, *only* take credit at banks you have **heard of**, where you **walk in** to their **physical building** where **they've been** for 10 years.

Answer (score -3):

Imagine he sends you the money on your account, and later on, some mafia guy nok your door asking for it.

Not only that, what about a few months later the anti-money laundry department nok your door to ask you about the transaction?

If you need money, go to the bank.